# backtracking algorithm for set cover

Tags: algorithm

Can someone provide me with a backtracking algorithm to solve the "set cover" problem to find the minimum number of sets that cover all the elements in the universe?

The greedy approach almost always selects more sets than the optimal number of sets.

Answer (score 2):

This [paper](http://bit.ly/9JoCO2) uses Linear Programming Relaxation to solve covering problems.

Basically, the LP relaxation yields good bounds, and can be used to identify solutions that are optimum in many cases. Incidentally, when I last looked at open source LP solvers (~2003) I wasn't impressed (some gave incorrect results), but there seem to be some decent open source LP solvers now.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem needs a little more clarification - it seems that you are given a family of subsets $$S_1,\ldots,S_n$$ of a set A, such that the union of the subsets equals A, and you want a minimum number of subsets whose union is still A.

The basic approach is branch and bound with some heuristics. E.g., if a particular element of A is in only one subset $$S_i$$, then you must select $$S_i$$. Similarly, if $$S_k$$ is a subset of $$S_j$$, then there's no reason to consider $$S_k$$; if element $$a_i$$ is in every subset that $$a_j$$ is in, then you can not bother considering $$a_i$$.

For branch and bound you need good bounding heuristics.  Lower bounds can come from independent sets (if there are k elements $$i_1,\ldots,i_L$$ in A such that each if $$i_p$$ is contained in $$A_p$$ and $$i_q$$ is contained in $$A_q$$ then $$A_p$$ and $$A_q$$ are disjoint).  Better lower bounds come from the LP relaxation described above.

The Espresso logic minimization system from Berkeley has a very high quality set covering engine.